# Cloudfront keeps redirecting me to index.html

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have a static website uploaded on S3 and recently I came to use Cloudfront as I wanted to serve it with https. Now my problem is that I have some js logic that based on the path, puts a "#" and scrolls around, but now for some reason it redirects me to mysite.com/index.html and breaks me the logic.

I would like how to avoid this behaviour, just as in localhost, with the base path "/" without any index.html at the end of it.

I've tried to set Default Root Object to "/" only but it seems to ignore it and keep redirecting, also I tried to invalidate it but nothing.

Also I have to say that I'm using 2 S3 buckets one with the "www" which redirects to the previously mentionated, for that reason I also created 2 cloudfront distributions.

Idk what im doing wrong but something has to be :S

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a default Root object with the object name.

example:
[www.bucket1.tld/](http://www.bucket1.tld/) (redirects to naked domain)
.bucket1.tld/**index.html** <---- you need to specify this as the default root object, not "/"

Your bucket can't find the default root object because "/" is a prefix, not an object. The redirect from www to naked domain is seperate from this and is working as intended.

Additionally - The bucket that is setup as the website is the one causing the "index.html" to be strapped to the back of your domain. This is because you've told S3 that the bucket is a website and that it needs to serve "index.html" as a default object.

Set your DRO to "index.html" in CloudFront.

- Eric
  Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html#DefaultRootObjectHowToDefine

Comment: This is so frustrating, I had it well configured but it looks like the invalidations or the cookies messed up, I tried opening the site with chrome (my default browser is brave) and it works perfectly, no weird redirects, no index, just my website as it is. Thank you for your time and information, was really helpful :)